# Nested ArrayList lookup

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, nested-loops

So I need to return the the departure point for a certain itinerary, here are few examples:

Trips := [ [A,B], [B,C], [C,D] ]
The trip in this example started at "A".

Trips := [ [D,E], [F,D], [E,X] ] 
The trip in this example started at "F".

For this I did 2 loops to compare A to C and D, if A doesn't exist nowhere then it is the departure point.

Is it possible to do it this way (keep the 2 loops) and change something in the condition to get the departure city only?

```
ArrayList<ArrayList> tripsList = new ArrayList<ArrayList>();
ArrayList<String> trip1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> trip2 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> trip3 = new ArrayList<String>();

tripsList.add(trip1);
tripsList.add(trip2);
tripsList.add(trip3);

trip1.add("Hamburg");
trip1.add("Berlin");

trip2.add("Mainz");
trip2.add("Frankfurt");    

trip3.add("Frankfurt");
trip3.add("Hamburg");

System.out.println(tripsList);

for (int i=0; i < 3 ; i++)
{
  for (int j=0; j < 3 ; j++)
  {
    if (tripsList.get(i).get(0)!=tripsList.get(j).get(1)) 

      System.out.println("your place is "+tripsList.get(i).get(0));
  } 
}`
```

Output is the following:

`[[Hamburg, Berlin], [Mainz, Frankfurt], [Frankfurt, Hamburg]]
your place is Hamburg
your place is Hamburg
your place is Mainz
your place is Mainz
your place is Mainz
your place is Frankfurt
your place is Frankfurt`

Comment: I forgot to mention that it is random, it is not necessarily at the beginning, so I need a function to find it.

Comment: Sounds a bit like a topological sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a flag to wait until you check all results:

```
Boolean anyMatches = False;
For (int i= 0; i < 3 ; i++) 
{
    anyMatches = false;
    For (int j= 0; j < 3 ; j++) 
    {
        If (tripsList.get(i).get(0) == tripsList.get(j).get(1))
        {
            anyMatches = true;
        }
    }
    If (anyMatches == False)  
    {
        SystemThen.out.println("Your Departure City is "+tripsList.Get(i).Get(0));
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thanks, that's exactly what I wanted to do! Is this the simplest and cleanest way to do it?

Comment: It is not the cleanest way because it continues through the inner loop even when we know we are not looking at the Departure City, and it continues through the main loop even after the Departure City has been identified.

Answer (score 1):

Once you find the departure the method stop searching, hope it can help you

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> tripsList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> trip1 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> trip2 = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> trip3 = new ArrayList<String>();

tripsList.add(trip1);
tripsList.add(trip2);
tripsList.add(trip3);

trip1.add("D");
trip1.add("E");

trip2.add("F");
trip2.add("D");

trip3.add("E");
trip3.add("X");

System.out.println(tripsList);

String departure = "";
for (int i = 0; i < tripsList.size(); i++) {
    if (!departure.equals("")) {
        break;
    }
    departure = tripsList.get(i).get(0);
    for (int j = 0; j < tripsList.size(); j++) {
        if ( j == i) {
            continue;
        }
        if (departure.equals(tripsList.get(j).get(1))) {
            departure = "";
            break;
         }
    }
}
System.out.println(departure);
```